# Не могу понять смысл слова static

Tags: java, static

Ребят, помогите мне понять, зачем перед функцией писать слово static?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Нестатические обычные методы можно вызвать у экземпляра класса, в котором они объявлены. Они имеют доступ к внутреннему состоянию конкретного экземпляра класса (его полям).

Статические методы не привязаны к какому-то экземпляру класса и могут быть вызваны без создания оного. Они не имеют доступа к нестатическим членам класса.

Таким образом, если вам в методе не нужно обращаться к состоянию конкретного экземпляра класса, то метод можно сделать статическим.

Answer (score 6):

Если перед функцией добавить модификатор `static`, метод будет принадлежать классу и для его вызова не надо создавать новый объект. Пример:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Math.pow(2, 2)); //4.0
    }
}
```

Метод `pow()` из `java.lang.Math` объявлен, как `static`. Поэтому мы его вызывали через класс, которому он пренадлежит:

```
public final class Math {

    @HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate
    public static double pow(double a, double b) {
        return StrictMath.pow(a, b); // default impl. delegates to StrictMath
    }
}
```

Надо также заметить, что статические методы могут вызывать только другие статические методы, имеют доступ только  к статическим переменным, не могут использовать `this` или `super`.

Answer (score 4):

Функция может принадлежать самому классу (это как раз статическая функция, для её создания используется слово static), а может - объекту этого класса. Статическая функция вызывается от имени класса и не зависит ни от одного из объектов класса. Вообще это не особенность языка java, статические функции есть в большинстве языков программирования, поддерживающих ООП. В интернете полно статей и примеров на тему, что такое статические функции и зачем они могут применяться. Формат stackoverflow не лучший для настолько общих вопросов)

Answer (score 2):

Объясню на простом понятном «пацанском» языке. Смотри у тебя есть класс в нем есть, допустим статическое поле с геттером и сеттером. Из какого то другого класса ты обращаешься к этому классу, не создавая экземпляр класса. Через сеттер записал данные. Теперь ещё из другого класса опять обращаешься к статическому классу и считываешь этот элемент . Как то так. С помощью статик формируется такой паттерн проектирования как синглтон.

```
public class A {
  public static int field;
}

public class Main{
 ...
 public static void main(){
  A.field = 5;
  C c = new C();//вывод 5
 }
}

public class C{
 ...
 public C(){
  System.out.println(A.field);
 }
}
```